# What details would you view in a certificate to check if it is trustworthy?

Tags: security, website, ssl, certificate, https

I have a question need help:

What details would you view in a certificate to check if it is a trustworthy website?

Answer (score 0):

The certificate itself gives no information about how trustworthy a website is. It only states, that they invested some money for a domain name and a certificate matching the domain name and that some certificate agency decided to sign their certificate because of the information provided. Some CA check the provided information a bit more and charge more money for it (so called EV "extended validation" certificates) but they will not check how trustworthy the site is.

Neither help any stickers on the site which claim to be from trusted security companies, because everybody might design this stickers and there is no technical restriction who can use it, so some (and especially phishing websites) put them on the site just because it looks more trustworthy.

A better reference is the community, e.g. what are the experiences other people have with this site, like if a web shop is not only cheap but also actually delivers their items etc. Of course, a web shop might turn bad later or have a shoddy internal security so your personal data gets compromised.

To summarize: the certificate might be used as a small indicator of trust. It should not be used as the only indicator and usually there are not enough good indicators to feel really safe. Just consider the internet as the wild wild west where everybody tries to make money and there are lots of shiny and trustworthy looking sites out there which have no problems with screwing you. It's like in real life, only that you have less reliable indicators on who you can trust.